# Move SKCameraNode using LERP through SKConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, lerp, skcameranode

I was just wondering if there is a way to implement a linear interpolation effect on my SKCameraNode while it is following my player node through use of SKConstraints. I am currently using constraints identical to the constraints used in Apple's Demo Bots tutorial. The alternative seems to be either using actions to reposition my camera with a delay/time, or changing the position with a delay directly in the update method. The camera scrolling as it is seems kind of jerky while the distance constraint to the player is set to a constant 0.0 like it is in Demo Bots. Please let me know your thoughts and all feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to go that extreme I think,  Just use `SKAction.move(to:duration:)`  to move your camera and change the timingMode to `.easeIn` and `.easeOut`

Comment: Sorry, should be `.easeInAndOut`

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by timing mode? I have looked in the skaction moveto:duration: and skcameranode docs and was unable to find what you were talking about. Also where would you initiate the action?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction